# how to calculate time hh:mm from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used to use below code to sum total numbers of one of the column from the GridView and use it as minutes figure:

```
int total = 0;
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            total += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Amount"));
        }
    }
```

the column data was just numbers, for example:

```
2
33
50
120
```

but now the data that retrieved for that column is nvarchar (hh:mm) and would like to sum it as, for example:

```
01:30
00:45
00:05
02:00
```

to be :

```
04:20
```

Comment: You could try [parsing the strings into TimeSpans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse) and add those? You might need to give it a format provider if it doesn't interpret the numbers as hh:mm by default. And you probably want some error or warning highlight if the parse fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string totalTime;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ts = ts.Add(TimeSpan.Parse((DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Amount")));
        var hourPart = ((int)(Math.Truncate(ts.TotalMinutes/60))).ToString().PadLeft(2,'0');
        var minutePart = (ts.TotalMinutes%60).ToString().PadLeft(2,'0');
        totalTime = hourPart+":"+minutePart;
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, i had to add .ToString() for ts

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutesInDouble), pass the above value in double format.

[Read this Aticle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromminutes.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string hours = @"
    01:30
    00:45
    00:05
    02:00";

    TimeSpan totalHoursSpan = hours.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
         .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Trim(), "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay)
         .Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (total, span) => total += span);


    string totalHrs = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", (int)totalHoursSpan.TotalHours, totalHoursSpan.Minutes);

    Console.WriteLine(totalHrs);

}
```

Outputting:

```
04:20
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `System.TimeSpan` to get the result in Time format

```
TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan();

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        var ts = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Amount").ToString(); 
        var t = DateTime.Parse(ts).TimeOfDay;
        totalTime += t;
    }
```

Comment: it worked but some output need some parsing, for example the results for : 00:24
00:08
00:20
00:05
15:15
16:20
00:05
is
1.08:37:00
while it should be  32:37

Comment: ```var ts = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem,TimeSpan.Parse("Amount")).ToString();``` does this work

Comment: it says (cannot convert from 'System.TimeSpan' to 'string')